# Outputting DataObjectManager in template include

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have followed the tutorial here http://doc.silverstripe.org/old/modules:dataobjectmanager to create a dataobjectmanager in my CMS.

It's all working perfectly there however I am having an issue getting it to output in the template. My code is as follows

```
<?php 
class InfoArea extends DataObject{ 
   static $db = array( 
      'Title' => 'Varchar(255)', 
      'Content' => 'HTMLText' 
   ); 

   static $has_one = array( 
      'ResortPage' => 'ResortPage' 
   ); 

   public function getCMSFields_forPopup(){ 
      return new FieldSet( 
         new TextField('Title'), 
         new SimpleTinyMCEField('Content') 
      ); 
   } 
}
```

ResortPage.php

```
....... 
static $has_many = array ( 
      "InfoAreas" => "InfoArea" 
   ); 
....... 
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Content.AdditionalInformation", 
         new DataObjectManager( 
         $this, 
         'InfoAreas', 
         'InfoArea', 
         array('Title' => 'Title','Content'=>'Content'), 
         'getCMSFields_forPopup' 
      )); 
........
```

I have a template "ResortPage.ss" which has an include "ResortInfo.ss". It is from within this include file that I need to output the DataObject.

I have tried the below but it doesn't output anything

```
<% control InfoArea %> 
   $Title 
   $Content 
<% end_control %>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. In the ResortPage class I had

```
static $has_many = array ( 
      "InfoAreas" => "InfoArea" 
   );
```

as well as

```
static $has_one = array ( 
      "InfoAreas" => "InfoArea" 
   );
```

..by mistake. I just needed the `has_many`.